# 2 mbps broadband or 512 kbps leased line

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

As per my understanding surfing means download the web page and all its images and display. So how fast my surfing speed will be must depend on how fast my download speed is.

Now i have a 2mbps broadband connection which gives me 2mbps surfing and only 300 kbps download speed and upload speed is just 64 kbps. In my office 8 Pcs are connected to this one broadband connection and employees work on all of them simultaneously. Since they are 8 Pcs so i get slow surfing speed on each of my Pc.

Will surfing speed on each PC increase if i switch my 2 mbps broadband to 512 kbps 1:1 leased line. I will be getting 512 kbps download and upload speed in leased line which will be more than 300 kbps download and 64 kbps upload speed in broadband.

Please suggest. I really need to improve surfing speed. Will 512 kbps 1:1 leased line provide faster surfing than 2mbps 1:8 broadband?

Comment: I presume when you say "300 kbps" you mean 300KB/s.

Answer (score 1):

> Will surfing speed on each PC increase if i switch my 2 mbps broadband to 512 kbps 1:1 leased line. I will be getting 512 kbps download and upload speed in leased line which will be more than 300 kbps download and 64 kbps upload speed in broadband.

No, it will probably get much worse. A 512Kbps line will give a peak download speed of about 62KB/s.

As you've noticed, a 2Mbps line gives a download speed of around 245KB/s. There are 8 bits in a byte and 1,024 bytes in a kilobyte. 2,000,000 / 8 / 1,024 = 244

A 512Kbps line will give a download speed of around 62KB/s. There are 8 bits in a byte and 1,024 bytes in a kilobyte. 512,000 / 8 / 1,024 = 62.5

Comment: 512KB/s leased line will give download speed 512 KB/s and upload speed also will be 512KB/S

Comment: @AbhinavSrivastava Right, but he's talking about a 512Kbps leased line. Line speeds are measured in bps.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your 2Mbps broadband connection limited to 300Kbps down? Typically the advertised bandwidth is relative to downstream so it would seem your downstream should be 2Mbps and your upstream remains 64Kbps. Have you performed any speed tests to see?

In terms of the leased line, is there an SLA associated with it? Broadband speeds can fluctuate and with an SLA there is usually a minimum level of service (speed, reliability, latency) before compensation begins. If you're only browsing i can't imagine the cost of a leased line is really worth it.

To make a decision I would say you need to evaluate the actual speed up and down you current receive, review any SLA the leased line might provide and then make a decision on what is best for your 8 PCs.